# Arithmetic subgroup and different embeddings

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a group that has an embedding $\phi_1:G\to\text{GL}(n,\mathbb Q)$. Suppose $H<\text{GL}(n,\mathbb Q)$ is commensurable with $\phi_1(G)\cap\text{GL}(n,\mathbb Z)$, then is there always another embedding $\phi_2$ of $G$ into $\text{GL}(n,\mathbb Q)$, s.t. $H=\phi_2(G)\cap \text{GL}(n,\mathbb Z)$?

The motivation is if there are 2 embeddings of $G$ into $\text{GL}(n,\mathbb Q)$, say $\phi_1,\phi_2$, then $\phi_1(G)\cap \text{GL}(n,\mathbb Z)$ and $\phi_2(G)\cap \text{GL}(n,\mathbb Z)$ are commensurable. (See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/391305/definition-of-an-arithmetic-subgroup-of-an-algebraic-group/391327#391327).) I am curious if the converse is true.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @Shaun I couldn't figure out anything. I would be very grateful if you could explain or give hints.